# Chromedriver headless mode doesn't work with https

Tags: python, selenium, https, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to visit a URL using Selenium chromedriver in headless mode, but it is not working.

I had it take a screenshot while in headless mode and this (http://prntscr.com/ize9f1) is what I got. The fact that it says "http" not "https" makes me think there is problem with https in headless chrome.

Going to this URL works perfectly if I just remove the --headless flag, it gives this (http://prntscr.com/ize9r9) result (I know this is an error too, but it's a simplified version of the URL I'm trying to visit. This error is not a problem, only the one I'm getting in headless mode).

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://cp.adidas.co.uk/idp/startSSO.ping')
```

If anyone knows why this might be happening and/or how I can fix it then it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add chromedriver version and chrome version also

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani They are both up to date

Comment: Looking at the screenshot it seems the site purposefully blocking you in chrome headless. This is not an issue with chrome as such

Comment: @JP Even I get the same error _Manually_ while trying to access the _url_ not only with `https` but also with `http`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DebanjanB Which error? Access Denied?

Comment: @TarunLalwani How can I fix that? It sometimes happens in headed mode too. I tried user agent but it didn't work. Headless chrome should be indistinguishable from chrome. I even hex edited out $cdc_ from chromedriver.exe.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I think it might be something to do with this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/2wBc9IJ10Ns/yb8lPmecSMkJ

I noticed this on headed chrome http://prntscr.com/izgrkb

Perhaps headless chrome has trouble dealing with that

Comment: I just tried to open the given url but there is an error in URL. Error is "SSO Error".

Comment: @Hiten Yes, as I said that error is totally fine, I'm not worried about that. My problem is I'm getting 

Access Denied 
You don't have permission to access "x" on this server. 
Reference #y - as shown in my first screenshot.

I only get the access denied error in headless mode, but I need to run it in headless.